# fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, datetimepicker

Вот весь код, который задействован

```
//Класс,в котором всё реализуется

public class AddingTaskDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

//Статический вложенный класс DatePickerFragment

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    public DatePickerFragment(){

    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }

}
//Метод, в котором реализуется весь функционал

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_task, null);

    final TextInputLayout tilTitle = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTitle);
    final EditText etTitle = tilTitle.getEditText();

    TextInputLayout tilDate = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskDate);
    final EditText etDate = tilDate.getEditText();

    final TextInputLayout tilTime = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTime);
    final EditText etTime = tilTime.getEditText();



    tilTitle.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.task_title));
    tilDate.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.task_date));
    tilTime.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.task_time));

    builder.setView(container);

    //Реализация

    etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etDate.length() == 0) {
                etDate.setText(" ");
            }

            /*Ругается на DatePickerFragment:
            * Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static
            */
            DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    dateCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    etDate.setText(Utils.getDate(dateCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    etDate.setText(null);
                }
            };
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment");
        }
    });


//Часть не задевающая мэйн код, но на всякий случай я её сюда вставил

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            final Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            if(etTitle.length() == 0) {
                positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                tilTitle.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
            }

            etTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                        tilTitle.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
                    } else {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                        tilTitle.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    return alertDialog;
}
```

}

Вот как я вызываю AddingTaskDialogFragment в коде MainActivity:

```
public void setUI(){
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment addingTaskDialogFragment=new AddingTaskDialogFragment();
            addingTaskDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "AddingTaskDialogFragment");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поискав в инете решения данной проблемы, я узнал, что данный вариант кода устаревший (2015 года) и если как-то его и использовать, то необходимо его почти полностью менять (в особенности DatePickerFragment на DatePickerDialog с таймпикером аналогично). Так что решения проблемы попросту нет, код уже никем не используется.

Answer (score 2):

Фрагменты как и активити и сервисы управляются системой. В т.ч. система может их восстановить после уничтожения процесса по к-л причине. Чтобы это работало система должна иметь информацию об этих компонентах. При этом она не может её получить из анонимного класса, о чём и сообщает.

Засим, вам надо заменить ваши анонимные классы на статические внутренние классы или обычные классы в отдельных файлах.

Comment: Даже после того, как я добавил сюда статический класс DatePickerDialog у меня выходит та же ошибка

Comment: Покажите в вопросе получившийся код. Если он похож на тот, что сейчас в вопросе то ошибка в том, что нельзя переопределять методы класса-фрагмента. Так оно не работает. Вам надо вызывать просто конструктор по умолчанию. `new DatePickerFragment()`

Comment: Я редактировал вопрос, жду ответа

Comment: @АлексейСухилин, покажите ещё как вы этот диалог отобразить пытаетесь. Ошибка должна быть там. Наверное у вас там код остался и первой редакции вопроса т.е. ничего не поменялось в причине ошибки.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю в чём дело, уже 4 дня на одном и том же этапе. Я могу в своём приложении создавать таски с заголовком, но когда нажимаю на EditText, которые отвечают за выбор даты и времени у меня просто приложение закрывается из-за того, что я собираю проект с ошибкой в DatePickerFragment и TimePickerFragment. Код один и тот же, что и в гайде, версия студии та же. Я в отчаянии

Comment: @АлексейСухилин, ну... Сейчас всё, вроде, правильно выглядит. Если всё ещё ошибки - выложите минимальный пример на gitHub в виде репы кою можно просто склонировать и запустить - возможно я смогу вечером глянуть что там не так.